# How to check if my mouse pointer in the left/right part of my screen on unity-C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouse

How to check if my mouse pointer in the left/right part of my screen on unity-C#

do I use :
get mouse position
then getting the x and y axis of it
will that work .

Comment: Have you tried what you suggest? Only the x is needed if left/right. You'd check if less than half of screen width, then it's on the left.

Answer (score 0):

well yes, you can simply check e.g.

```
if(Input.mousePosition.x < Screen.width / 2f)
{
    // => left half
}
else
{
    // => right half
}
```